# What does Deming regression estimate?

Tags: regression, estimation, loss-functions, errors-in-variables, total-least-squares

Least squares regression estimates conditional means.

Least absolute regression estimates conditional medians.

Quantile regressions estimate conditional quantiles (a special case of which is the absolute loss mentioned above giving conditional medians).

Analogously, what does [Deming regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression) estimate?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that Deming regression approximates something like an underlying data generating process.

That is different from a statistical relationship like conditional means, medians or quantiles.

Comment: I get this, but then when we apply the regression equation to some feature values (perhaps features used in training, perhaps not), what is that output value? In quantile regression, there is a clear interpretation as a conditional quantile. If we minimize square loss, we can interpret the value as a conditional mean. Perhaps "conditional" is the wrong notion for Deming regression, but then what does that $(X, \hat y)$ mean? (Or is it meaningless? I don't see how that could be, but maybe that's why I have the question.)

Comment: @Dave in many applications of regression the role of $x$ and $y$ are considered seperate. $y$ is seen as a value to be predicted by the values $x$, or $y$ may be even seen as dependent (e.g. in controlled experiments where $x$ is idependent from the experimental/sampling variations and pre-determined). Deming regression makes more sense when a relationship between variables is investigated when the role between $y$ and $x$ are less clear. For instance they are both observed with an error. The Deming regression estimates the underlying process. It may be less typical, but that is what it does.